# How do i deserialize this xml file

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am deserializing an xml file (I need to sort the nodes/objects by GUID and then re seralize it) and i cannot properly deserialize it

I have created classes but the file is not getting read properly. The classes are listed in the second block of code, also, if the value monitored is labeled false they must be ignored and not written to the file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnvironmentNodeConfigurationParameters>
  <ComplexDeviceParameterList>
    <ComplexNodeConfigurations SubDeviceID="Controller_1" SubDeviceName="Controller_1">
  <ComplexNodeParameterList>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="Temperature" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="128" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="ABAABB1E-CCFE-4BF2-BBFC-90142F1B177A" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="Temperature_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="0" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="8dcc904e-1484-43d2-8bf1-3dc19f01951d" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="LowTemp_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="40" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="3d73a245-2766-40ca-b77a-b777af79e215" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="HighTemp_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="41" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="db4059d4-bb26-467c-9e36-4c755d9a5e98" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="LowTemp_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="2" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="fa11e66b-c269-4790-887d-0ac4bb30541d" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="HighTemp_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="4" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="0e4653bf-e43b-4725-9f00-731d5e356f12" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="Temp_Offset" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="9" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="1d0c6fa0-6819-4b7e-8145-536954b8bdd7" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="PV1_Temperature" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="134" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="b921d2a7-997b-4a32-8460-1a63177f1711" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="Output" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="130" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerOutput" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="c87482e3-edb5-46b9-9fdc-8915d49eeb1e" Enabled="true" Units="Percent" Monitored="true" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="132" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerStatus" ValueType="System.Int32" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="b59cbbc5-c286-4f6c-ae99-b3a822808fc7" Enabled="true" Units="" Monitored="false" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="1" NodeName="Circuit_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="139" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerStatus" ValueType="System.Int32" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="4f90d425-ba0b-401d-b339-795e5411a1f0" Enabled="true" Units="" Monitored="false" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
  </ComplexNodeParameterList>
</ComplexNodeConfigurations>
<ComplexNodeConfigurations SubDeviceID="Controller_2" SubDeviceName="Controller_2">
  <ComplexNodeParameterList>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="Temperature" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="128" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="{85F59633-FF15-4FF7-A419-8BF9B7C80FF8}" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="Temperature_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="0" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="3ed6fee4-8a63-43f4-87be-83f45f81e524" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="LowTemp_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="40" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="d11a0fbf-b92b-42b4-9423-9be0081c0cdf" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="HighTemp_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="41" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="4ecc10ff-c189-4e39-971d-dd8e0cbfddf0" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="LowTemp_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="2" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="1d891f0f-1ab0-487d-a5eb-77fe089240e7" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="HighTemp_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="4" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="5d54d839-4d17-43c1-82a8-14c6199b6ab2" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="Temp_Offset" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="9" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="e6bbe973-9a94-4aeb-b104-7a3460962244" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="PV1_Temperature" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="134" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="95f03a54-cb4e-48f8-93c5-e6e4ce9a1a4c" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="Output" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="130" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerOutput" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="04802db4-aea9-4787-97c0-3eca56c802b0" Enabled="true" Units="Percent" Monitored="true" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="132" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerStatus" ValueType="System.Int32" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="218f7c0a-bb21-49eb-b36a-4c0ed00e1b07" Enabled="true" Units="" Monitored="false" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="2" NodeName="Circuit_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="139" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerStatus" ValueType="System.Int32" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="aeb98aec-a688-47d3-afda-3b6bf9bb1a43" Enabled="true" Units="" Monitored="false" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
  </ComplexNodeParameterList>
</ComplexNodeConfigurations>
<ComplexNodeConfigurations SubDeviceID="Controller_3" SubDeviceName="Controller_3">
  <ComplexNodeParameterList>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="Temperature" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="128" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="1CD619B5-9E1B-448E-9A5B-7BFF4B480813" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="Temperature_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="0" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="97ba767c-7dd9-4c74-b3ea-fd40ff48927e" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="LowTemp_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="40" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="9fa1ae56-7d43-4da9-b481-09a1befee510" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="HighTemp_SetPoint" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="41" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="7c9b72dc-0150-4dfd-8b72-6f79def6de7d" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="20">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="LowTemp_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="2" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="353117b2-dd05-4b67-a8f1-afda5570afc6" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="HighTemp_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="4" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="6a7852a4-9d29-413b-bda2-674176774a7c" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="true" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="Temp_Offset" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="9" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="6660cbd6-ebbb-49cc-a622-dab1df02c263" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="PV1_Temperature" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="134" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerTemperature" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="186445bc-d0d4-4227-87e6-016918be1160" Enabled="true" Units="Celcius" Monitored="false" ReportItem="10">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="Output" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="130" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerOutput" ValueType="System.Double" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="b707e3a5-91c1-4c15-9021-e1035d605421" Enabled="true" Units="Percent" Monitored="true" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="132" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerStatus" ValueType="System.Int32" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="d27d00ce-6696-4d92-9236-9fae182134b6" Enabled="true" Units="" Monitored="false" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
    <NodeConfigurations NodeID="3" NodeName="Circuit_Alarm" DependNodeName="" RegisterType="HoldingRegs" StartReg="139" NumRegs="1" NodeType="FreezerStatus" ValueType="System.Int32" EnvironmentLinkType="Amtn" Guid="4eacd952-3a7f-4b8e-b0d1-6054b1dfd996" Enabled="true" Units="" Monitored="false" ReportItem="0">
      <EnvironmentLinkParams>
        <KeyValuePair Key="IPAddress" Value="192.168.1.250" />
      </EnvironmentLinkParams>
    </NodeConfigurations>
  </ComplexNodeParameterList>
</ComplexNodeConfigurations>
```

```
 [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("EnvironmentNodeConfigurationParameters")]
    public class EnvironmentNodeConfigurationParameters
    {
        [XmlElement("ComplexDeviceParameterList")]
        ComplexDeviceParameterList cdpl = new ComplexDeviceParameterList();

    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class ComplexDeviceParameterList
    {
        [XmlElement("ComplexNodeConfigurations")]
        List<ComplexNodeConfigurations> cnc = new List<ComplexNodeConfigurations>();
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class ComplexNodeConfigurations
    {

        [XmlElement("ComplexNodeParameterList")]
        ComplexNodeConfigurations cnc2 = new ComplexNodeConfigurations();

    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class ComplexNodeParameterList
    {
        [XmlElement("NodeConfigurations")]
        List<NodeConfigurations> nodeList = new List<NodeConfigurations>();
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class NodeConfigurations
    {


        [XmlElement("EnvironmentLinkParams")]
        List<EnvironmentLinkParams> elplist = new List<EnvironmentLinkParams>();
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class EnvironmentLinkParams
    {
        [XmlElement("KeyValuePair")]
        KeyValuePair kvp = new KeyValuePair();
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class KeyValuePair
    {
        [XmlElement("NodeConfigurations")]
        List<NodeConfigurations> nodeList = new List<NodeConfigurations>();
        [XmlAttribute("Key")]
        public string key = "IPAddress";
        [XmlAttribute("Value")]
        public string value = "192.168.1.250";
    }
```

I need the code to take the xml file, deserialize it sort by GUID and then reserialize it.

Comment: Object in the classes have to be public to serialize and deserialize.  It also look like you have some recursion in the classes that have to be fixed.  Use following line : public ComplexNodeParameterList cnc2 = new ComplexNodeParameterList();

Comment: That did help but didnt solve it completely

Comment: What isn't working?  I didn't check every node.

Comment: it just doesnt deserialize

Comment: Try changing KeyValuePair class which may get confused with the Net object to KP.

Comment: tried that im getting frustrated now haha (not with you just the program)

Comment: I posted my entire code with the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my program :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EnvironmentNodeConfigurationParameters));
            EnvironmentNodeConfigurationParameters parameters = (EnvironmentNodeConfigurationParameters)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            List<ComplexNodeConfigurations> cncs = parameters.cdpl.cnc;

            foreach (ComplexNodeConfigurations cnc in cncs)
            {
                List<NodeConfigurations> nodeList = cnc.cnc2.nodeList;

                nodeList = nodeList.OrderBy(x => x.guid).ToList();
            }

        }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("EnvironmentNodeConfigurationParameters")]
    public class EnvironmentNodeConfigurationParameters
    {
        [XmlElement("ComplexDeviceParameterList")]
        public ComplexDeviceParameterList cdpl { get; set; }

    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class ComplexDeviceParameterList
    {
        [XmlElement("ComplexNodeConfigurations")]
        public List<ComplexNodeConfigurations> cnc { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class ComplexNodeConfigurations
    {

        [XmlElement("ComplexNodeParameterList")]
        public ComplexNodeParameterList cnc2 { get; set; }

    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class ComplexNodeParameterList
    {
        [XmlElement("NodeConfigurations")]
        public List<NodeConfigurations> nodeList { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class NodeConfigurations
    {
        [XmlElement("EnvironmentLinkParams")]
        public List<EnvironmentLinkParams> elplist { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Guid")]
        public string guid { get; set; }

    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class EnvironmentLinkParams
    {
        [XmlElement("KeyValuePair")]
        public KP kvp { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class KP
    {
        [XmlElement("NodeConfigurations")]
        public List<NodeConfigurations> nodeList { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Key")]
        public string key { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Value")]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think its an issue with the classes could you help me with those?

Comment: is there a way to implement a sorting function (by GUID) into this as well? Im sorry, im very bad with C#